# Shortest way to integrate

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^ \frac {\pi}{2} \frac {\sin(11x)}{\sin(x)}~dx$$
Is there any short way to integrate it?

The actual question is, how to integrate the following: $$\int \frac {\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx$$ where $n$ is odd number.

Can anyone explain.

Comment: Functions such as $\sin$ and $\log$ can be written using `\sin` or `\log`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, one way, that is short and possible to generalize, is to show that (for example by using Euler's formula and a geometric sum)
$$
\frac{\sin 11x}{\sin x}=1+2\cos 2x+2\cos 4x+\cdots+2\cos 10 x.
$$
Then term-wise integration is easy.

Comment: The answer is always pi/2 i.e independent of n, if ni odd .. how can we calculate

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Comment: I need you to show some effort. If not then I'm sorry but I have more interesting activities tonight... So, please play with what I gave you for a while, and you will probably see how it works.

Comment: Can you explain euler formula and ageometri sum of $\sinnx/sinx$ in detail . From where you got this

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora My answer explains how you can apply Euler's formula and the geometric series, however, it is far from "any short way to integrate it"

Comment: I already got it but i cant understand from where the sin11x/sinx expansion expansion came from i.e written by mickep

Comment: Hm, I do suppose I didn't need any complex analysis... Indeed, the terms do simplify greatly, as this answer implies.

Comment: This type of calculation is very common in Fourier analysis, compare for example with the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel).

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Well, see the second half of my solution for a more explicit version of mickep's answer.

Comment: Oh duh!  Dirichlet kernel lol... see... I don't do Fourier analysis... so I wouldn't happen to remember such things :-)

Answer (score 5):

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}~\mathrm dx$$

Note that by symmetry and Euler's formula,

$$4I_n=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}~\mathrm dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}~\mathrm dx\tag1$$

## From here, here's my solution:

Now consider the substitution $z=e^{ix}$ to get

$$4I_n=-i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^n-\frac1{z^n}}{z-\frac1z}~\frac{\mathrm dz}z=-i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^n(z^2-1)}~\mathrm dz$$

This is easily managed using the Cauchy's differentiation formula and gives

$$4I_n=\frac{2\pi}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-2}}\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^2-1}$$

One then applies the geometric series and differentiates term by term

$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-2}}\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^2-1}&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{2k}\\&=(n-1)!\end{align}$$

And thus,

> $$I_n=\frac\pi2$$

---

## Starting back at $(1)$, we can derive mickep's solution:

One may apply the geometric series to see that

$$\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{2kix}+e^{-2kix}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos(2kx)$$

This may be integrated easily from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and gives

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}~\mathrm dx=\frac\pi2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin(n\pi)-\sin(0)}{2k}=\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is to let $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}dx$$

And then consider $$I_n-I_{n-2}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(n-1)xdx$$ using the factor formula.

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining and your time. Is there any way to make factor formula

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora see the second set of four formulas here...http://www.trigonometry-help.net/trig-formulas.php

Comment: Great real approach.  People don't take the time to look at this carefully, but that last integral comes down to $0$, which makes the entire problem a lot more trivial than it first looks.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yup so you only need to work out $I_1$ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\mc{C} \equiv \braces{z\ \ \mid\ z = \expo{\ic\theta}\,,\ \theta \in \pars{0,{\pi \over 2}}}}$:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin\pars{11x} \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\expo{11x\ic} - 1 \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\Im\int_{\mc{C}}{z^{11} - 1 \over \pars{z - 1/z}/\pars{2\ic}}
\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\,\Im\int_{\mc{C}}{1 - z^{11} \over 1 - z^{2}}\,\dd z =
-2\,\Im\int_{1}^{0}{1 - y^{11}\expo{11\pi\ic/2} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
2\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}}}
_{\ds{=\ \arctan\pars{1}\ =\ {\pi \over 4}}}\ -\
2\ \underbrace{\cos\pars{11\pi \over 2}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\
\int_{0}^{1}{y^{11} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y = \bbx{\pi \over 2}
\end{align}